# Simulate browser resize on page first load

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a dashboard web application. It contains some controls on it which are sized based on the browser and are also resizeable by the user. They are dynamically created and, as such, I persist their dimensions through  page postbacks by storing their state in Session and in a database.

When my dashboard first loads there is a chance that I am pulling data out of the Database onto a monitor which is not the same size as when the data was written to the Database. The controls need to be resized proportional to how they were before. Fortunately, it appears that the controls are able to resize themselves to the correct, proportional dimensions if they believe they need to re-calculate their dimensions.

As such, on first page load, I would like to simulate the browser resizing. Is it possible to do something like this in javascript?

Comment: If using jQuery it's as easy as `$(window).resize();`.

Comment: @marcel in javascript is as easy as window.onresize();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The controls probably resize on [window.onresize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onresize). If you want to trigger this event you can do `window.onresize();` after the page loads.

To wait for the apge to load you can add it to the `window.onload` event.

Comment: I receive this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onresize' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

Comment: (I do not receive the error using jQuery, but I am not experiencing the results I was anticipating, so making sure I'm not doing anything unexpected.)

Comment: @sean anderson hey, did you sort it out?

Comment: Well, I bound an alert to window.onresize, and call jquery's $(window).resize and saw the alert, so I am making the assumption that the jQuery method would be sufficient, yet I still do not see what I was hoping for so I've forwarded the question along to third-party control support. Thanks for your solution though, curious it didn't fire properly.